# Finding relative x and y value on a sprite [Gamemaker]

Tags: sprites, coordinates, game-maker, orientation

I'm having a little conundrum that may just result from a lack of knowledge of Gamemaker's functionality. I've attached two images to aid explanation.

[image]

[image]

I have a sprite of a turret (with a gun barrel), attached to a turret object, and at certain points in gameplay this object will spawn another object on top of it (let's call it the 'bullet object').

I would like the bullet object to spawn at the x and y coordinates at the end of the gun barrel. This would be easy to find as a pair of coordinates if the sprite was always stationary, in this configuration. Alas, it is not. It rotates like billy-oh. This means that the x and y coordinates at the end of the gun barrel are constantly different.

How do I find this constantly changing x and y coordinate? I imagine (though am most likely wrong) that there the initial x and y coordinates of the sprite are saved and can be found even if rotated; is there a function that does this? Or do I need to write a script and then call it every time I want to spawn the bullet object?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26311662/1821428

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. I have another related problem, but I'll post another question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @Dmi7ry, for posting the answer to this question above in the comments. The functions to use here are `lengthdir_x` and `lengthdir_y`, as explained in the link to the other question.

For my purposes, I knew that the point on the turret that I want my bullet to appear at was 62 pixels out from the origin. The functions `lengthdir_x` and `lengthdir_y`allow you to find a set of coordinates out from an object's x/y origin by specifying how many pixels out from source you want, and in which direction. I knew that I needed to find a point 62 pixels out from origin, and that that point would need to be in whichever direction the turret object (and thus its barrel) was pointing, determined by the `image_angle`. Therefore:

```
instance_create(x + lengthdir_x(62, image_angle), y + lengthdir_y(62, image_angle), oBullet)
```

Comment: This answer would be improved for future users if you explained *how* those functions should be used and how they apply to the original problem statement.

Comment: Excellent point, have just done so.